# Checking if the website is reachable with or without www

Tags: python, http, web, https, server

How to check if the website is reachable with or without `www`. For example the following URL:

```
https://corteva.in/
```

is unreachable. But when entered like (with www):

```
https://www.corteva.in/
```

it correctly displays in the browser. Is there a way I could check this with python?

I tried the following:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname('www.corteva.in')
socket.gethostbyname('corteva.in')
```

both resolve to some IP address. But when loading in the browser like `https://corteva.in` the browser is never able to load the web service.

Comment: There are several steps and it depends on what you mean by "reachable". If you are able to connect to port 443 that's the next step; then try to fetch a page and see if that succeeds. Then in some systems you'll want to check if the content you get is actually the correct content. But that's probably outside the scope of what you are asking here.

Comment: @tripleee By reachable I mean, it must be accessible via web browser. If you try `https://corteva.in/`, the browser just keeps on waiting,trying to load, but nothing appears until I add `www`. This is something I want to know.

Comment: That's what "are you able to connect to port 443 and fetch content" means.

Comment: @tripleee No, `https` without `www` does not work. How do I check this?

Comment: You try to connect to port 443. You attempt to request the resource `/` with a `GET` request. The `requests` library does all of this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests

def attempt_connection(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=1)
        print(f"Website {url} connected with status code {r.status_code}.")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
        print(f"Website {url} timed out.")


attempt_connection("https://corteva.in/")
attempt_connection("https://www.corteva.in/")
```

outputs:

```
Website https://corteva.in/ timed out.
Website https://www.corteva.in/ connected with status code 200.
```